# centering in a two column document in latex

Tags: tables

I want to put the table in the center of the page of a two column document.

This is my original code

```
\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{{Method}} & \multirow{2}{*}{{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}temperature \\ \end{tabular}}} & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{{B}}                               & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{{C}}                                \\ \cline{3-10} 
                                 &                                                                                & {Region1}   & { Region2}    & { Region3}   & { Region4}  & { Region5}   & { Region6}    & { Region7}   & { Region8}  \\ \hline
{Timberlake {[6}{]}}     & {98}                                                                   & {81.2}  & {95.9}  & {73.6}  & {12.2}  & {32.5}  & {91.5}  & {11.59}  & {3.2}  \\ \hline
{Agnewl {[8}{]}}     & {99}                                                                   & {82.2}  & {54.2}  & {67.2}  & {87.2}  & {81.2}  & {32}  & {1.3}  & {44.0}  \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\vspace{0.1cm}
\caption {List  with Temp vs regions  } \label{tab:title}
\end{table}
```

I tried `\begin{center}` and `\centering` but none helped.

Could someone advise?
How could I put this table in center of a two document page?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Your table is centered but on a page which is much broader -- with other words: Your table is **too** wide! Please post working examples, not just fragments of code

Comment: Could you post a *complete* minimal working example?

Comment: put it in `\begin{table*}\centering\begin{tabular}` the `*` form spans both columns

Answer (score 1):

I propose two solutions: exchanging rows and co, so it can fit in a column width, ore use the `strip` environment, from the `cuted` package (`shipunov` bundle), which allows  full width objects in two-column documents. Of course, these do not float,  a have to replace `\caption` with the `\captionof` command.

I took the liberty to improve the table to my taste, removing all vertical lines, and using the rule commands from `booktabs`:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}%
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{cuted, ragged2e}
\usepackage{lipsum, array, booktabs, caption}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[11]

\begin{table}[!htbp]
  \centering\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
  \begin{tabular}{@{}lccc@{}}
    \toprule
    \multicolumn{2}{l}{Method} & Timberlake {[6}{]} & Agnewl {[8}{]}\\
    \multicolumn{2}{l}{Temperature} & 98 & 99 \\
    \midrule
    \multirow{4}{*}{B} & Region 1 & 81.2 & 82.2 \\
                       & Region 2 & 95.9 & 54.2 \\
                       & Region 3 & 73.6 & 67.2 \\
                       & Region 4 & 12.2 & 87.2 \\
    \addlinespace[2ex]
    \multirow{4}{*}{C} & Region 5 & 32.5 & 81.2 \\
                       & Region 6 & 91.5 & 32 \\
                       & Region 7 & 11.59 & 1.3 \\
                       & Region 8 & 3.2 & 44.0 \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{List with Temp vs regions } \label{tab:titlenew}
\end{table}

\lipsum[2-4]

\begin{strip}
  \setlength\arraycolsep{4pt}
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}*{8}{c}c@{}}
    \toprule
    \multirow{2}{*}[-0.6ex]{Method} & \multirow{2}{*}[-0.6ex]{Temperature} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{{B}} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{{C}} \\
    \cmidrule(lr){3-6}\cmidrule(l){7-10}
                         & & Reg.\,1 & Reg.\,2 & Reg.\,3 & Reg.\,4 & Reg.\,5 & Reg.\,6 & Reg.\,7 & Reg.\,8 \\
    \midrule\addlinespace
    {Timberlake {[6}{]}} & {98} & {81.2} & {95.9} & {73.6} & {12.2} & {32.5} & {91.5} & {11.59} & {3.2} \\ \addlinespace
    {Agnewl {[8}{]}} & {99} & {82.2} & {54.2} & {67.2} & {87.2} & {81.2} & {32} & {1.3} & {44.0} \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
  \captionof{table}{List with Temp vs regions } \label{tab:title}
\end{strip}

\lipsum[4-8]

\end{document}
```

[image]